# Laravel exception thrown when rendering 404

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 9 (latest) site which is throwing an exception when rendering core 404 blade.

Exception: htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, _ given .../var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views/404.blade.php

404.blade.php

```
@extends('errors::minimal')

@section('title', __('Not Found'))
@section('code', '404')
@section('message', __('Not Found'))
```

**If I change __('Not Found') to 'Not Found', the exception is not thrown and the 404 page renders correctly.**

This is not an issue on my local environment, but I'm using the same PHP version 8.1.22.

UPDATE:
Trace...

```
#0 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(123): htmlspecialchars(Object(_), 3, 'UTF-8', true)
#1 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Concerns/ManagesLayouts.php(53): e(Object(_))
#2 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views/404.blade.php(3): Illuminate\\View\\Factory->startSection('title', Object(_))
#3 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(109): require('/var/app/curren...')
#4 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(110): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem::Illuminate\\Filesystem\\{closure}()
#5 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(58): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->getRequire('/var/app/curren...', Array)
```

TIA

Comment: Is `__('Not Found')` for translation? Why not use a variable in blade? `@php $not_found = __('Not Found'); @endphp @section('title', $not_found)`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using variable?

```
@php
    $not_found = __('Not Found');
@endphp
@section('title', $not_found)
```

It is looking for plain string.

Not sure why the 2nd param of `@section` does not accept the translation method: `__('Not Found')` Based on the documentation, it accepts string. So I suggested to use a variable instead of the translation method.

Comment: how does it make any difference?

Comment: @OMiShah updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  This is one of the core exception handler templates.  I can override, but I'm trying to determine why __('...') is not returning a string or not being parsed correctly as it is probably indicative of another issue.

Comment: @bfuzze Most probably before the `@section` recognize the string `__('Not Found')`, they see the `_` and giving error not recognizing this method. Not 100% sure but it might be a reason.